# Variable expansion inside parentheses and quotes

Tags: bash, shell-script, variable, quoting, jq

In the script below, I can't seem to make $var1 expand in the second statement. I've tried `$var1`, `${var1}`, `echo $var1` and `'$var1'`. It is inside a few sets of quotes and parentheses which I guess is what is causing the problem. Any ideas?

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get the AutoScalingGroupName for the NameNode ASG
var1=$(aws cloudformation list-stack-resources --stack-name abc123 | jq '.StackResourceSummaries[] | select(.ResourceType=="AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup")' | jq '.PhysicalResourceId' | tr -d '"' | grep nn); echo $var1

var2=$(aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-instances | jq -r '.AutoScalingInstances[] | select(.AutoScalingGroupName == "$var1") | select(.AvailabilityZone == "us-east-1a") .InstanceId'); echo $var2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Variables in single quotes are not expanded.  Try this...

```
var2=$(aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-instances | jq -r '.AutoScalingInstances[] | select(.AutoScalingGroupName == "'"$var1"'") | select(.AvailabilityZone == "us-east-1a") .InstanceId'); echo $var2
```

Comment: Did `$var1` need to be inside double quotes outside of the single quotes?  If it has instead been ` == "'$var1'") `  would that have had the same effect?  Maybe the quotes prevent whitespace in the value for $var1 from being interpreted as starting a new argument

Comment: Don't inject shell variables into the `jq` expression. Pass them with `--arg` instead.

Answer (score 0):

It is wrapped in single-quotes, so it cannot be expanded.

```
jq -r '.AutoScalingInstances[] | select(.AutoScalingGroupName == "$var1") ... .InstanceId'
```

The key part is the `jq` command that you are actually only passing a single argument to (notice the long *red* part of the command). So your pipes are also not taking effect. You can selectively wrap things in quotes that truly need to be.

Comment: Micah, thanks for your feedback but I'm not exactly sure what you mean. Once I made the change suggested above, it produced the output I was expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Shell variables are not expanded within single quotes.

In this case, you don't really *want* to inject the the `var1` shell variable in the `jq` expression without first encoding it as a JSON string though, which is what you do with the `--arg` option to the utility:

```bash
jq --arg name "$var1" '... | select(.AutoScalingGroupName == $name) ...'
```

This way, you create a `jq` variable called `name` with the JSON-encoded string from the `var1` shell variable.

Your full script may written like this (also simplifying the other bits of code):

```bash
#!/bin/sh

resourceId=$(
    aws cloudformation list-stack-resources --stack-name abc123 |
    jq -r '
        .StackResourceSummaries[] |
        select(.ResourceType == "AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup").PhysicalResourceId |
        select(contains("nn"))'
)

instanceId=$(
    aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-instances |
    jq -r --arg name "$resourceId" '
        .AutoScalingInstances[] |
        select(
            .AutoScalingGroupName == $name and 
            .AvailabilityZone == "us-east-1a"
        ).InstanceId'
)

printf 'instanceId = "%s"\n' "$instanceId"
```